# Secure ad function - resourceId cannot be empty - API access

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, azure, azure-functions

I have been following this guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi

When deploying my spfx web part and trying to approve API access I get the 'resourceId cannot be empty' error.

Been stuck on this for a couple of days, any help is much appreciated :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the App ID URI of your AAD app? It was generated automatically for you in the past, but that's no longer so if you're missing it, it could explain your issue.

Comment: Sorted it, I think I had the URI wrong. Thanks dude.